# define field name in JavaScript object literal from variable

Tags: javascript

**i need to change the field dynamically**

```
   this.search = function(search, match) {
          var deferred = $q.defer()
          search({
            size: 10000,
            index: "products",
            body: {
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  [search]: {
                    "query": match,
                    // "operator": "and",
                    type:"phrase"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

**but its showing the  error   30:16  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token [**

Comment: What browser & version are you running this in?

Comment: The name `search` is overloaded. It is used both as the name of a function and also as a parameter of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to split it up so you can build the **body** object dynamically:

```
var body = {
    "query": {
        "match": { }
    }
};
body.query.match[search] = {
    "query": match,
    "type": "phrase"
};
```

Comment: in elastic search this is not possible

Comment: It won't let you pass **body** as a pre-defined object? Seriously? That is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an AngularJS problem - the problem is you are trying to use a *Computed Property Name* for the object literal when the browser you are using doesn't support it.

**Computed Property Name documentation link:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

To see the which browsers can & can't use *Computed Property Names*:

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_computed_properties